Push notification not getting in android app
I am not receiving notifications through FCM after migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1? The server sends the notification, but an error appears stating "Entity not found."
The server is attempting to send notifications through HTTP v1, but sometimes encounters an "Entity Not Found" error, causing notifications to not be received in the Android app.

I'm missing a question. Putting a questionmark behind a sentence does not make it a question(im talking about "I am not receiving notifications through FCM after migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1?") :P
I have some questions for you:
What does this have to do with laravel? What have you tried? What are you looking for? Has it worked in the past? If so, what has changed? Do you think its a code error or a config error? Can you share any of the code/config?
